# How to speed up a part (selection) of a Camtasia Video Recording?

Tags: video, camtasia

I want a part (selection) of a camtasia video recording to speed up? Do you have any clue on how to do this?

Comment: Found the answer on http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-clip-speed.html minute 1:30

Answer (score 23):

Cut the part you wish to speed up, click right mouse button on it and choose "clip speed" option from the menu. Input 200, 300 or even 1000% if you wish to speed up, or 10, 20, 30% if you wish to slow down your video.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to slow down the editing clip speed, you need to make a new track and move the selected part to it. After this, you need to edit the clip speed and it will work perfectly.

https://gyazo.com/e43c408ed3be39e30a07b98f1081e156

Note that splitting it away from the rest, will not work.

https://gyazo.com/d076b39161739dcaeb2a48899a985734